# How is it possible for the shares of a privatized company to still be traded on the US OTC stock market?

Tags: united-states, stocks, private-company, adr, pink-sheets

At one point, [Noble Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noble_Group) was among the largest commodity trading firms in the world. During 2015-2019, the company was accused of accounting fraud, reported huge losses, and was facing insolvency and bankruptcy. The company was delisted from the Singapore Exchange, underwent debt restructuring to avoid bankruptcy, and now operates as a private company.

On the US OTC stock market, Noble Group's shares are still being traded in the form of ADRs ([NOBGY](https://www.otcmarkets.com/stock/NOBGY/overview)) and F shares ([NOBGF](https://www.otcmarkets.com/stock/NOBGF/overview)). Its shares are classified under the OTC Markets' "Pink Current Information" category.

How can the ADR and F shares of such a company continue to trade on the US OTC stock market even after the company was delisted and privatized?

Comment: Doesn't "private company" just mean it doesn't trade on a stock exchange? Presumably you're still allowed to go to a shareholder and say, "psst, Mr Shareholder, want some money? I'll take those pesky shares off your hands"

Comment: @NorgateData Please do not answer questions in the comments section. Your answer is fine - just move it to the answer field.

Comment: Thanks Orange Coast - comment deleted and posted an extended answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it's a PUBLIC company. Noble's shares just are not listed on an exchange, and they also have no plans to do so. You can certainly trade them in bilateral trades, with quotations facilitated by venues such as OTC Markets but none of that is a formal stock market.

More info here: https://noblegroupholdings.com/faq-shareholder

Regarding ADR - at some stage this ADR was a sponsored ADR, which would have involved the market maker having some level of holding, so the listing still stands.

Regarding the Foreign OTC listing - the OTC Markets designation of "Pink Current" is simply that - a designation from a given party.  Regardless of the designation, the shares still exist and can be traded bilaterally.  Given the illiquidty of such trading, there is bound to be a lot of volatility around price discovery.